# Image Maps not resizing properly

Tags: html, css, imagemap

I am using https://github.com/stowball/jQuery-rwdImageMaps to resize my image maps.

```
<img id="transparentImage"  onclick="point_it(event);" src="../images/transparentImage.png" usemap="#transparentImageMap" border="0" />
<map name="transparentImageMap">
<area shape="poly" Coords="1117 ,22 ,1117 ,35 ,1117 ,49 ,1119 ,63 " href="#"/>
</map>
```

In the ready event

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var wh = $(window).width();
    var ht = $(window).height();
    $('img[usemap]').rwdImageMaps();
});
```

As soon as i am giving

```
 $('img[usemap]').rwdImageMaps();
```

in the ready event the mapCordinates are changing and not fitting properly. This is happening before resizing only when the page gets loaded.

Thanks

Comment: I've used this successfully, and the only difference between what I've used and what you have is I have an id on my map: `<map name="transparentImageMap" id="transparentImageMap">`

Comment: Hey,Thanks. I solved it also. Found that the image which was 1X1 which i was expnading on the ready event using jquery. But in the resize plugin it was picking up the image size as 1X1 only and thats why the problem. Thanks Anyways :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks. I solved it also. Found that the image which was 1X1 which i was expnading on the ready event using jquery. But in the resize plugin it was picking up the image size as 1X1 only and thats why the problem. Thanks Anyways :)